# Laplacian of electric potential in inhomogeneous media

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, dielectric

I am confused about a problem on capacitance of a lossless inhomogeneous dielectric sandwiched between conductors. The permittivity of the medium is expressed as  $\epsilon = \epsilon_0(1 + sin\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the polar angle in a spherical coordinate system.

The sample solution starts by asserting $\nabla^2V = 0$, however I cannot see how do we find that.

Starting from $\nabla \cdot\vec{D} = \rho$ from [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193543/the-truest-most-general-maxwells-equations-in-isotropic-linear-inhomogeneous) and $\rho = 0$ since no free charge distribution exists,

$$\vec{D} = \epsilon\vec{E} = -\epsilon \nabla{V}$$
$$\nabla \cdot (-\epsilon\nabla{V}) = 0$$

From the identity giving the divergence of a scalar times vector,
$$\nabla \cdot (-\epsilon\nabla{V}) = -\epsilon(\nabla \cdot \nabla V) + \nabla V\cdot(\nabla(-\epsilon)) = 0$$

The first expression is $\nabla^2V$ and the second expression should reduce to zero for the Laplace equation to apply, but $\epsilon$ is space-dependent and should have a nonzero gradient.

Any feedback would be appreciated.